# Why does my MatTableDataSource push more than one Object?

Tags: angular, typescript, datasource

I have 2 subscriptions in my ngOnInit().

Here I can add a 'Transaction' to a transaction pool. When clicking on "Send" it will trigger the `transaction$` subscription and add the transaction to the pool. It should always only add ONE transaction.

[image]

This is how the pool looks like for the first time:

[image]

This is what the console.logs give me: This should always be the case. After pushing a transaction in each of the 10 pools they should all contain 1 object.

[image]

After clicking on one button, the number of the winner is getting subscribed. The pool from the winner should be copied to the rest of the pools. 
And what happens now, when I add a transaction to the pool:

The transaction is getting pushed to each of the 10 pools. But instead of getting pushed 1 time it's getting pushed 10 times in each pool.

[image]

This is what the console.logs show:

[image]

```
this.emitTransactionService.transaction$.subscribe(transaction => {
        if (transaction !== false) {
          for (let i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
            console.log(this.transactionPools[i].dataSource.data);
            this.transactionPools[i].dataSource.data.push(transaction);
            console.log(this.transactionPools[i].dataSource.data);
          }
          console.log('Hallo');
          this.sendMessage5();
        }
      }
    );
    this.emitTransactionService.winningMiner$.subscribe(winningMiner => {
      if (winningMiner !== false) {
        for (let i = 1; i < 11; ++i) {
          this.transactionPools[i].dataSource = this.transactionPools[winningMiner].dataSource;
        }
      }
    });
```

I tried several things, but none of them worked. I tried creating a new MatTableDataSource after each button click, which didn't work. 
And also the problem appeared when I added the `winningMiner$` subscription

Comment: call me crazy but I am pretty sure the i < 11 portion of your for loop is the culprit

Comment: I tried it with 10. It didn't change anything unfortunately.

Comment: How many times do you want that for loop to run?

Comment: Always 10 times.